# Python - Импорт модуля из другой директории

Tags: python

У меня есть такая структура проекта:

```
project
-dir1
--main.py
-dir2
--__init__.py
--some_file_i_need.py
--some_dir_i_need
---__init__.py
```

Нужно из `dir1/main.py` импортировать `dir2` (целиком).
По типу:

```
from .. import dir2
dir2.some_dir_i_need()
```

Но при попытке сделать также появляется ошибка:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: питон не умеет в линуксовые `.`/`..`, ему нужно говорить примерно так: `import ..dir2`

Comment: и чтоб это все нормально работало, надо в инит файл этой директории подтянуть все, что хочешь в дальнейшем использовать

Comment: @finally уже пробовал - Syntax error (python 3.8.3)

Comment: чет я глупость написал... если вы хотите все что только можно из нее вытянуть, напишите так `from ..dir2 import *`

Comment: @finally теперь такая же ошибка, как и в вопросе

Comment: не должно быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import sys

## укажите путь до файла

sys.path.append("/dir1")

from main import dir2

Comment: костыль, разве нет?

Answer (score 0):

Я создал такую директорию. Сразу оговорюсь что создание главного скрипта в папке модуля является что-то типа [антипатерна](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3122/). но предположим что такой кейс все же есть.

```
.
├── dir1
│   └── main.py
├── dir2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── some_dir_i_need
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test.py
│   └── some_file_i_need.py
└── main.py
```

Первое что я делаю - восстанавливаю справедливость, создаю файл в папке с проектом (на верхнем уровне)

**project/main.py**

```
from dir1.main import *
```

**project/dir1/main.py**

```
print('import2')
from dir2 import *
test()
```

**project/dir2/**init**.py**

```
import dir2.some_file_i_need
from dir2.some_dir_i_need import *
from dir2.some_dir_i_need.test import *
```

**project/dir2/some_file_i_need.py**

```
print('import2')
```

**project/dir2/some_dir_i_need/test.py**

```
def test():
  test()
```

В итоге я получаю такой **вывод**:

```
import1
import2
test
```

Насколько я понимаю это все происходит от того что директория запуска как бы запекается и если она имеет более высокий уровень чем все используемые модули то проблем не возникает, при условии что мы либо явно прописываем импорты и не забываем про `__init__.py`  либо указываем все необходимое для импорта в этих файлах.